# "org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported" Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, post, spring-security

I am using angular JS and Spring MVC+Spring Security in my application. When using $http like below:

```
$http.post('/abc/xyz/'+catalogId);
```

it is giving below error:

org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
WARNING: Request method 'POST' not supported.

Moreover I've put POST in my controller as well:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/xyz/{catalogId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody List<Category> getCategorybyCatalogId(@PathVariable(value = "catalogId") long catalogId, ModelMap modelMap,
            HttpSession session) throws IOException {
        if (catalogId != 0) {
            return menuService.getCategorybyCatalogId(catalogId);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

this problem started coming when **I added spring security** config class.
Please help!!

Comment: You have a different url in post and your controller. Try making them same and see if it works

Comment: what does your server route look like?

Comment: @LearningPhase: url is okay, abc is the project name.

Comment: Where you able to resolve this?

Comment: I just did csrf().disable(); for now. that works but that is not a proper solution in my opinion. yet to find out the solution.